# $d\pi(X)$ is skew-symmetric. What does it mean?

Tags: representation-theory

This is from a lemma in **Lang $SL_2$**

> If $\pi$ is a unitary representation of G, and $X \in \mathfrak g$, then $d\pi(X)$ is skew symmetric on $H_\pi^\infty$

What does skew symmetric mean here? And why does it follow straight from definition of the derived representation?

My understanding is that it should mean:

$$\langle d\pi(X)v,w\rangle = -\langle v,d\pi(X)w\rangle$$

where $v, w \in H_\pi^\infty$. But it is not obvious to me why this should follow from the definition of the derived representation as the Lie derivative, i.e. as $d/dt \pi(\exp(tX)v$ evaluated at zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is in the Lie algebra, then you know that $$\langle \exp(tX)v,\exp(tX)w\rangle$$ is constant, that is, it does not depend on $t$. Differenttiate with respect to $t$, and evaluate at $t=0$.